# Can anyone explain how it is possible that the same VUE.js multidimensional array is displaying different data?

Tags: arrays, vue.js

I am working on creating Conway's game of life using VUE.js. Every one second, I want to set the displayed array called boardArray to be equal to the nextBoardArray. When I do this and console.log the array I get different data depending on how it is displayed.

In my code I am doing this

```js
vue.boardArray = vue.nextBoardArray;
      console.log("this is right after boardArray is set to nextBoardArray   " + vue.boardArray)
      console.log(vue.boardArray)
```

and my console is outputting this - [My Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17eR5.png)

You can see there are 1's present in the string but not when the object is displayed.

Comment: it is a string concatenation with array which is converting in string

Comment: Is the multidimensional array logging showing the whole array?

Comment: is there really no code executed between both log statements?

Comment: Yes the whole array is being displayed in both instances but the data appears to be different and my application is acting as though those 1's don't exist. It is true that there is really no other code executed between the log statements.

Comment: How is vue.nextBoardArray being set?

Comment: My gut is telling me their is a watcher or computed proerty that is mutating it, which would cause the results you are displaying.